# Delay release from buffer until promises after it are done

Tags: rxjs

Here is my pseudo-code:

```
const s = new Subject();

s.pipe(
  bufferCount(1).pipe(
     concatMap(() => new Promise()),
     concatMap(() => new Promise()),
     concatMap(() => new Promise()),
  )
)

s.next('a');
s.next('b');
s.next('c');
```

I want "b" and "c" held in the buffer UNTIL "a" is done processing.

Is this possible?

Comment: the pseudo-code is quit confusing. What is concatMap(() => new Promise()),

Comment: @FanCheung thanks for the comment even though it was confusing. My goal is to have `bufferCount` wait to "release next batch" if any of the promises are still running. The `bufferCount` shoudl continue to collect to buffer while the promises are running, BUT not release.

Comment: You can `s.pipe(concatMap(...` and Promises will resolve in order. Can you produce a working demo with your problem?

Comment: Thanks @JuliusDzidzevičius I'll create a demo and post soon. I need the buffer to continue collecting to buffer while the stuff in the pipe is running. But teh buffer should not do another .pipe until the last .pipe finished running.

Comment: Maybe `exhaustMap` could be used, but still not sure about the issue

Comment: Thanks for being so into trying to help. I got real busy with work so couldn't post repro yet.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you want a `source` Observable to trigger some task and then only have the next value from `source` trigger the next task when the previous task completed. You can achieve this by `zipping` your `source` with a second trigger (`startNext`) that indicates that the previous task is done and the next value from `source` starting the next task can be emitted.

```ts
import { Subject, zip, of, BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs';
import { map, tap, delay, concatMap } from 'rxjs/operators';

const source = new Subject();
const startNext = new BehaviorSubject(null);

zip(source, startNext)
  .pipe(
    map(([s, n]) => s), // discard the 'startNext' trigger
    concatMap(s => of(s).pipe(delay(1000))),
    concatMap(s => of(s).pipe(delay(200))),
    concatMap(s => of(s).pipe(delay(3000))),
    tap(_ => startNext.next(null))
  ).subscribe(s => console.log('result for', s));

source.next('a');
source.next('b');
source.next('c');
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-g5efuc

Comment: Very interesting, thanks for this! I got busy at work but will definitely try this out! I don't see any buffering in here though. But I'll post a reproducible example soon.